# How do I send a post request to Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, amazon-ec2, request, amazon-cloudfront

I can't send a post request to Cloudfront that I set up for my Ec2s. I get the 404 and 400 error. How do I request requests to my EC2 machines via cloudfront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because by default the `Allowed HTTP Methods` for a CloudFront distribution are `GET, HEAD`.

From the console perform the following:

- Click on your distribution
- Click on the `Behaviours` tab.
- Select your behaviour and click `Edit`
- Under the `Allowed HTTP Methods` select `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE`
- Click `Yes, Edit`

This process might take upt an hour to rollout to all Edge locations, but normally is much quicker.

Below is a screenshot of the option from the interface.

[image]

Comment: I activated Cloudfrount yesterday. I have accepted all methods since I activated. I still get the 404 and 400 error

Comment: Have you checked your instance logs to see if the requests are being forwarded through?

Comment: This is my ec2 machine access log. I think I get a user-agent error. I have to use my own user-agent, but cloudfront deletes it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfdK5.png)

Comment: I see from your logs it hits the web server which means it is your web server returning the 404 (page not found). Does it work without CloudFront?

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks to you, it came to my mind to look at the logs. User-agent was creating problems. I removed it improved. Thank you.

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)